# Optimizing functions for lists to avoid looping in R

Tags: r, performance

I am working with a large list of values in `R`. I need to apply some functions to each element of the list. The list I use is `i1` and is produced by the next code:

```
i1=list(0)
i1[1:120000]=runif(120000,min = 10000,max = 100000)
```

In `i1` I have to apply a some functions in order to get a new dataframe using as input each value in the list. The functions are the next: `f_1` computes a new value using as input each value in `i1` by using some conditions. In this function I used some conditionals in order to obtain the value. The function is the next:

```
f_1=function(x)
{
  y=ifelse((x/18)>20,x-(x/18),ifelse(x>20,x-20,ifelse(x==0,0,x)))
  return(y)
}
```

Second function is `f_2`. This function uses as input `f_1` and it is composed of a `for` structure where there are 160 iterations. In this function an empty vector is created. Then, the vector grows by applying `f_1` function. The final result of `f_2` is a dataframe with all the elements produced in the `for` structure. The function is the next:

```
f_2=function(v)
{
  x=c()
  y=v
  x[1]=y
  for(i in 2:160)
  {
    x[i]=f_1(x[i-1])
  }
  x=x[!duplicated(x)]
  x=c(x,0)
  z=as.data.frame(t(abs(diff(x))))
  return(z)
}
```

Finally, to apply both `f_1` and `f_2` to `i1` I use the package `plyr` in order to apply the functions to the list. I built this function for that activity:

```
compute=function(x)
{
  y=f_2(x)
  return(y)
}
```

By using `compute` I can apply the functions for all elements in the list. I use this code for that:

```
L2=llply(i1,compute)
```

All worked fine but it is taking long time to produce the final result:

```
system.time(llply(i1,compute))
   user  system elapsed 
 436.71    0.92  447.70
```

I think the reason why the process is too slow has a basis in the function `f_2` because it uses a loop inside it. I have looked for some ideas to avoid this structure but I do not have a clear idea how to change `f_2` to be more efficient. Please, could you help with some directions about solving this issue? I have knowledge of functions but for this case I used a `for` inside the function to create my wished result.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You could improve the execution time of the loop dramatically if you didn't grow an object in it. Allocate `x` to it's final size and assign to its elements. (I've had to write this so often lately that I feel like a broken record.) Of course, you still won't beat a vectorized solution, but it wouldn't be that slow.

Comment: I wonder where you learned that bad habit of `x <- c(), for (i in 1:n) x[i] = something`.

Comment: Thanks @Roland sometimes I use `for` but in this time is taking long time to perfom the activity and I can't establish a way for example to use `*apply` family functions. For this reason I am looking for help to learn how to avoid this kind of mistakes in my code.

Comment: It's quite simple. Change the line `x=c()` to `x = numeric(160)` and you should see a much better performance.

Comment: Also, since you pass `f1` only single values, use the faster `if` and `else` instead of `ifelse`.

Comment: @Roland Thanks for your feedback, that is new for me I was accostumed to the creation of vectors and loops and I can not see in a clear way how to adapt my functions with your recommendations.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are several problems with your code. For example you make the classic mistake of growing objects in a loop.

However, if you are unhappy with performance of your code, you should start profiling it:

```
Rprof()
L2=llply(i1,compute)
Rprof(NULL)
summaryRprof()$by.self
#                       self.time self.pct total.time total.pct
#"ifelse"                    3.38    35.58       4.06     42.74
#"f_2"                       2.28    24.00       9.48     99.79
#"f_1"                       1.46    15.37       5.52     58.11
#"as.vector"                 0.86     9.05       0.86      9.05
#"as.data.frame.matrix"      0.32     3.37       1.44     15.16
#"paste0"                    0.20     2.11       0.22      2.32
#"is.na"                     0.20     2.11       0.20      2.11
#</snip>
```

You see that most of the time is spent in `ifelse` , `as.vector` and `as.data.frame.matrix`. It's not quite obvious where `as.vector` is called<sup>[1]</sup>, but the other two are obvious.

You can get slightly better performance using `if` and `else` instead of `ifelse`, but it doesn't help that much. I would instead turn `f1` and the  `for` loop in `f2` into compiled code using Rcpp (it's very simple with RStudio). Obviously you need the tool chain, i.e., install [Rtools](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/) on Windows.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

double f1 (const double x) {
  if((x/18)>20) return x-(x/18); 
  if(x>20) return x-20; 
  if(x==0) return 0; 
  return x; 
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector f2_1 (const double init, const int n){ 
  NumericVector res(n);
  res(0) = init;
  for (int i=1; i<n; i++) res(i) = f1(res(i-1));
  return res;
}
```

This is written faster than coming up with a vectorized pure-R solution (provided one even exists).

We can define the rest of your `f2` as:

```
f_2a=function(v)
{
  x = f2_1(v, 160)
  x=x[!duplicated(x)]
  x=c(x,0)
  z=abs(diff(x))
  return(z)
}
```

Note how I leave out `t` and `as.data.frame` because data.frames should be avoided if performance matters. They are more designed for convenience than for performance. Vectors can store the equivalent information of a one-row all-numeric data.frame and I can't imagine a good reason to return a list of one-row data.frames.

Now we call the funtion:

```
L2a = lapply(i1, f_2a)
```

Let's test if results are equal:

```
all.equal(L2[[1]], as.data.frame(t(L2a[[1]])))
#[1] TRUE
```

And now compare timings:

```
system.time(llply(i1,compute))
# user  system elapsed 
#13.91    0.00   13.93 

system.time(lapply(i1, f_2a))
#user  system elapsed 
#0.26    0.00    0.27
```

---

[1] It's called in a loop in `as.data.frame.matrix` splitting the matrix into a list of column vectors.

Comment: A very good answer... Another option is to throw more computing resources at the problem via `parallel::parLapplyLB`. Though, as you note, it's better to optimize the serial code first before parallelizing.

Answer (score 3):

One way to gain performance here is to **use vectors/matrices**.

So firstly you could either create you data as a vector by doing so

```
i1 = runif(120000,min = 10000,max = 100000)
```

or converting it into a vector like so

```
vector1 = unlist(i1)
```

and when you're done convert it back to list

```
list1 = list(vector1)
```

### New Functions Structure

Having vectors you'll be able to make use of **logical indexing**  and `f_1` would look like this:

```
f_1=function(x)
{
  y = rep(NA,length(x)) #initialize y filled with "NA"
  y[(x/18)>20] = x[(x/18)>20] - (x[(x/18)>20]/18)
  y[x>20] = x[x>20] - 20
  y[x == 0] = x[x == 0]
  return(y)
}
```

This way `y` will have the calculated value for every `x`.

### Optimization Points:

- Using vectors/matrices
- Initializing vector/matrices before hand

### Other Possibilities

Comparisons used more than once (such as `(x/18)>20`) can be stored and and reused to gain performance. For example `y[(x/18)>20] = x - (x/18)` would turn into:

```
condition1 = (x/18)>20;
y[condition1] = x[condition1] - (x[condition1]/18)
```

This way the condition will be calculated only once instead of three times.

### Final Notes

- Be aware that if you do not cover all the testing possibilities you may end up with `NA's` in your array.
- You could also initialize it with some other value, the default one, if have one. Just change `NA` to whatever data you want to fill it with. Like so `y = rep(NA,length(x))` -> `y = rep(0,length(x))` (filling with zeros).
- Note that commonly `<-` is used as the assignment operator in R, I just used `=`to avoid misunderstandings.