# for loop why appending to an empty object

Tags: r, for-loop

i am currently working on for loops. I have encountered this explanation of the structure of the code (output, sequence and body), as regards the fact we start a for loop by appending to an empty object the output of the loop.
"Before you start the loop, you must always allocate sufficient space for the output. This is very important for efficiency: if you grow the for loop at each iteration using c() (for example), your for loop will be very slow."

I do not understand what it means by growing the for loop at each iteration, and why it would take longer ? Could anyone enlighten me ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Optimizing functions for lists to avoid looping in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36369123/optimizing-functions-for-lists-to-avoid-looping-in-r)

Comment: `the R inferno` dedicated an entire circle of R-hell to growing objects. I suggest you read it (and the rest of the book ;-) ). https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno_090109.pdf

Comment: quote: *You may wonder why growing objects is so slow. It is the computational
equivalent of suburbanization. When a new size is required, there will not be
enough room where the object is; so it needs to move to a more open space.
Then that space will be too small, and it will need to move again. It takes a lot
of time to move house. Just as in physical suburbanization, growing objects can
spoil all of the available space. You end up with lots of small pieces of available
memory, but no large pieces. This is called fragmenting memory.*

Comment: @Wimpel thanks for the reading tip ! yet i do not understand his lines of code on page 9 as regards the for loop : lsum <- 0

for(i in 1:length(x)) {
  lsum <- lsum + log(x[i])
}
Why does he add "lsum <- 0" at the beginning ? What is he trying to compute with this loop ?

Answer (score 1):

A quick example:

```
fgrow <- function(n) {
  x <- c() # before we can modify "x" in the for loop, we must create it
  for (i in 1:n) x[i] <- i
}

fpreallocate <- function(n) {
  x <- integer(n)
  for (i in 1:n) x[i] <- i
}

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(fgrow = fgrow(1e5),
                               fpreallocate = fpreallocate(1e5),
                               check = "equal")
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>          expr     min       lq      mean   median       uq     max neval
#>         fgrow 10.9303 11.55675 12.307449 12.35355 12.55415 17.2237   100
#>  fpreallocate  2.4625  2.59760  2.641518  2.63460  2.67295  3.0574   100
```

In the `fgrow` function, R has to allocate memory to hold the entire updated `x` object. In this example, this happens 100k times, and the amount of memory it has to allocate grows on each iteration.

In the `fpreallocate` function, R allocates memory for `x` only once. Then it simply modifies a portion of that memory on each iteration.