# How can we assign value to a variable in a while loop?

Tags: r, while-loop, assign

My code is:

```
Storage<-c()
x<-1
while(x<10){
   Storage<-c(Storage,x)
   x<-x+1}
```

Is there a way to assign the values to the "Storage" without using c() and what is the purpose of using c(Storage, x) here?

Many thanks

Comment: Why don't you want to use `c`? Also, `c(Storage, x)` appends the old results of storage to the new ones.

Comment: If you don't want to use `c`, then you can look at the logic of the loop. You are concatenating the numbers 1-9 into a vector. You can simply use `x <- 1:9`

Comment: There is no reason. However, why would not I use only ```Storage<-x``` . In the end, x is increasing by 1 and I should be able to store without c(). I could not understand the purpose of using c()

Comment: You can use `Storage[x] <- x` to write `x` into the _xth_ element of `Storage`. If you try just `Storage <- x`, then you replace the _whole_ of `Storage` with the single value `x`. The version using `c(Storage, x)` appends `x` onto the end of `Storage`, but that creates a new vector each time, which is slow.

Comment: Take a look at [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73049791/9463489).